# The custom field in devise user model is not being verified before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, customization

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails and I have been trying to solve this issue for a long time but I have not seen any success so far.

In my project I am using devise for User authentication. In the user model generated by devise, I have added two custom attributes through migrations.
1st one is the username of type string and 2nd attribute will be the role of type integer which will be used as enum to store the role of current user.

I have updated the devise views as well for showing the role drop down menu to user during signing up and signing in but I am facing following issue.

Whenever I try to login, it just checks the db for whether the given email exists or not. If there is any record against the email, it logins the user otherwise not. What I want is that during login the field of user roles should also be verified whether its true or not.

Right now my application controller contains following code

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :password, :role])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :current_password, :role)}
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :role)}
    end
end
```

The output during this login process on the rails terminal is shown below

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2022-05-17 12:32:26 +0500
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<token>", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "role"=>"manager", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["email", "test@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 269ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Kindly help me out here

Answer (score 0):

In the application controller you can add a method and check the roles in it.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.manager? # or current_user.manager?
    ...
  else
    super
  end
end
```

[Link to the documentation of the method where exactly how it works is explained](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers:after_sign_in_path_for)

And if you want to additionally verify the user by username, you need to uncommet config.authentication_keys in device config `app/config/initializers/device.rb` and add there username and email.